# How to send check from US Bank to US location when I am abroad without checks

Tags: united-states, banking, check

I am in Europe and I am being asked to send a check via mail to a location in the US.

- I do have a PNC Bank Account
- I do not have any checks with me

Is there a way that I could achieve this quickly?

Comment: Look at their online bill pay. They might have the ability to mail a check for you to any address.

Answer (score 5):

Online banking is the easiest and obvious way.

Log in to you bank account, and use 'bill pay' to add the recipient address. The bank will mail a check in your name to the recipient.

If you have no login, create one. Your bank's website offers that, and it's straight forward. You don't need to be physically in a bank or even in the US, just know your name and personal data.
You can also call their help line to help you if needed.